# Check if point belongs to the plot

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart to draw XYPlot. What I'm currently trying to do:

1. User clicks on the plot and the app gives him back the coordinates of the chosen point; I think that I've got it right. Here is some code:

   ```
       public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent arg0) {
              Rectangle2D plotArea = chPanel.getScreenDataArea();
              XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
              double chartX = plot.getDomainAxis().java2DToValue(arg0.getTrigger().getPoint().getX(), plotArea, plot.getDomainAxisEdge());
              double chartY = plot.getRangeAxis().java2DToValue(arg0.getTrigger().getPoint().getY(), plotArea, plot.getRangeAxisEdge());
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "   x: "+chartX+ "  y: "+chartY);}
   ```
2. I need to determine if user clicked on the line or not. The target is to mark the clicked spot if it is on the drawn graph.

I would be grateful for any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of working with coordinates, add a [`ChartMouseListener`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseListener.html) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8002959/230513). You can examine the [`ChartMouseEvent`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseEvent.html) and any corresponding [`ChartEntity`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/entity/ChartEntity.html) for a variety of details.

Comment: As I understand this works for BarChart, selecting entire Bar. I need to select choosen point on XY Chart, so I'm not sure if I can use it. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
ShapeUtilities.intersects(java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D rect1, java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D rect2)
```

where rect2 can be "0" rectangle (for your points).