# how does zoomRange() works?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I need to zoom out from rangeAxis in `jFreeChart`, so I've used [zoomRange](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#line.1597) for this purpose.

But I didn't understand what is `lowerPercent` and `upperPercent`?

I want to set the rangeAxis as shown below in the image. How can i do that?

I've tried this but don't know what should be the value of `rangeAxis.zoomRange(0,?)`

```
public class Profilee  {



    double last=0;
    ChartFrame frame1;

    JFreeChart chart;
    ChartUtilities cu=new ChartUtilitiesImpl();

    public void generateProfile(double[] pointValue,double[] distance){
        ArrayList pv=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList dist=new ArrayList();

        pv.add(pointValue);
        dist.add(distance);

        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("");
        for(int i=0;i<pointValue.length-1;i++){

              series.add(last,pointValue[i]);
              last=distance[i];
         }



      XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
      chart= ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart("Profile View Of Contour", "Distance", "Contour Value", xyDataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

      ValueAxis rangeAxis = chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis();

      //rangeAxis.setLowerBound(-3);
      rangeAxis.zoomRange(0,?);     //What should be Value over here?
      frame1=new ChartFrame("XYLine Chart",chart);

      frame1.setVisible(true);
      frame1.setSize(1300,700);
    }


    public static void main(String ar[]){
        Profilee pro=new Profilee();
        double[] pv={3,2,3,0,5,-2,10};
        double[] dist={1,4,8,12,14,20,24};
        pro.generateProfile(pv, dist);



    }

    private static class ChartUtilitiesImpl extends ChartUtilities {

        public ChartUtilitiesImpl() {
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default, `ValueAxis` automatically adjusts its range to accommodate the dataset. You can adopt an explicit range, such as shown in the image above, using one of the `setRange()` methods.

```
rangeAxis.setRange(-8, 12);
```

Comment: can i set/get the distance of between two numbers of `rangeAxis`? For ex. rangeAxis ranges from -4 to 4, so can i get the distance between any two numbers on `rangeAxis` suppose 2 and 3?

Comment: Honestly, I try to avoid it; as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10156483/230513), a `ChartMouseListener` often obviates the need for model/view coordinate transformation.

Comment: can't i find it directly without `ChartMouseListener`?

Comment: Yes, but only by inverting the coordinate transformation. The real question is this: Why do you need to know?

Comment: Then use `setRange(2, 3)` to make 2 near the bottom and 3 near the top. The chart will scale to fill the container.

Comment: suppose the distance between 0 and 4 in the image shown above is 16 pixel then i want to set this as distance in between number's in my graph, that means numbers 0 to 4 in my graph should also have the distance of 16 pixel, and it should not be changed until i resize the image. This is what i want to do..

Comment: Do you mean you want to adjust the size of the enclosing container to make the axis 11 ticks * 16 pixels/tick tall? Why?