# Java Bar chart clickable bars

Tags: java, netbeans, jfreechart, bar-chart

Is there is a way to click on a JFreeChart bar to lunch an event ? if there's any other chart libraries which support clickable bars please guide me to it, what i really need is after creating the chart the user is able to click on one of the bars to do some other work is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [`ChartMouseListener`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartMouseListener.html) to the enclosing `ChartPanel`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8002959/230513).

[image]