# Inserting a button in a jfreechart graph

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I used a code in order to display a graph. I want to insert a button in this graph (Show details) that i will used in order to present some details about the graph .I tried with this code but an error appear:"cannot add to layout:constraint must be a string" 
thanks.

```
if(jCheckBox1.isSelected()){
    try{

      Statement statement = con.createStatement(rs.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,rs.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
      String sql1 = "Select last_updated_by,(count(id_incident) )*100/(Select count(id_incident) from incident where Status like 'Closed' and open_time between '"+date1+"' and '"+date2+"')from incident  where  Status like 'Closed'and open_time between '"+date1+"' and '"+date2+"' group by last_updated_by";
      rs1 = statement.executeQuery(sql1);
      DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset(); 
      while(rs1.next()){      
      pieDataset.setValue( rs1.getString("last_updated_by"),rs1.getDouble(2));                        
 }
      JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("Taux résolution par personne",  pieDataset, true, true, true); 
 PiePlot3D piePlot3d = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
     piePlot3d.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0}={1}"));
  fenetre fen= new fenetre();
      JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new CardLayout()); 
   fen.setContentPane(pnl); 
fen.setVisible(true);
fen.setSize(500, 500); 
 showdetails = new JButton(new AbstractAction("showdetails") {

          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
          }
      }) ;

       ChartPanel cPanel1 = new ChartPanel(chart);    
        pnl.add(cPanel1,showdetails);
    File fichier = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\résultat_application\\Taux résolution par personne de '"+date1+"' à '"+date2+"'.png"); 
       try { 
  ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(fichier, chart, 400, 250); 
} catch (IOException e) { 
  e.printStackTrace(); 
}   
              }
           catch (Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e);
              }
    }
```

Comment: Debug my code... Could you at least format your code properly ?

Comment: Please update your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30461001/230513) with your revised approach.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the line:

```
pnl.add(cPanel1,showdetails);
```

cPanel1 is a `ChartPanel`, showdetails is a `Button` - both are `Components`. However `Container` (from which JPanel inherits it's add methods) has no method that allows adding two components at once. What it does have, and the reason why it compiles is a method with the following signature:

```
add(Component comp, Object constraints)
```

And so it tries to match your button as a constraints object and decides that something is not right.

Comment: Deltharis thank you for your answer.but i don't undrestand what should i do?

Comment: @jalel Umm... Use an add method correctly - probably just `pnl.add(cPanel1); pnl.add(showdetails);`

Comment: i used it.the error disappear.but  the button (show details) doesn't appear

Comment: @jalel, it's probably because the ChartPanel doesn't have a layout. Try `pnl.setLayout(new FlowLayout())`, and then add the button.